# Identify uploaded document

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision, qr-code

We have page in business app where clients download word documents, sign them and upload back. 
Task is to make some key for downloaded docs to identify them when upload back.
Currently we think about make qr code when download and make qr code finding and decoding when upload signed doc. But I didn't have experience with qr and wondering is it hard task to find qr in uploaded doc?
Or maybe you can suggest other idea for identifying document?
Any out of the box free libraries are appreciated

Comment: if let us know why you need to identify the document we can help more. is it for security purposes and prevent the user to send you word documents that has malicious code inside ? or is it to detect that a customer made a mistake or its for detect that they signed it ? Or it is to identify them and relate them to the users. if it is to identify the document and related it to the user, then why you dont ask more information from the users in the upload form ?  do you have a registration option for the users ?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a GUID with [`Guid.NewGuid()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx), convert it to a string, [insert it programmatically into the Word document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b9478cs.aspx) (preferably in the footer), and save the GUID in a DB row as well, identified by client.

This means that every time a document is downloaded, your web site has to modify the file before sending it to the client.

Then you have to worry about the case where a given client downloads file, signs it and uploads it, then signs it differently and uploads it again.

Don't use a QR code unless there's a requirement for somebody to scan it visually.

### Update

Turns out they scan and upload, so there's a requirement for somebody to scan it visually. Use a QR code.

Comment: I forget to mention that client will download document, sign, Scan and upload. So name will be changed after scan. So name and date time impossible to use

Comment: Date/time can't possibly be a unique ID, and name is too easily changed. If they're scanning and uploading, use a QR code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real right or wrong answer to this question; it is mostly going to be opinion based. What I can do is give you what I may do.

I would keep control of the filename; if they download, signed, and upload a file called "Form1.docx", when they upload the file rename it with a DateTime stamp making it "Form1_170613-2006.docx" which would tell you when it was uploaded.

If the person has a username in your system (or similar), you could append that in the filename too; making it "Form1_170613-2006_JohnSmith.docx".

I've seen some systems where a GUID or an MD5 hash is used; I do not really care for these in most implementations as they are not sort friendly. The exception would be of a "constructed" GUID that would have a DateTime stamp at the beginning of the string OR if you are using a database such as SQL Server which can generate a GUID using NewSequentialID which are sortable.

As for the QR Code, my opinion is there is no really need for this in your context.

Comment: I forget to mention that client will download document, sign, Scan and upload. So name will be changed after scan. So name and date time impossible to use

Comment: Date & Time would be from when they upload. Can they upload anything they want? Do they specify what it is via any controls on the page?